# How to convert Binary data from database to String(text)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have uploaded my MS word file in Database in binary format. I am able to retrive it back. But I am planning to open up the word file in read only mode. I have done much operations on the file which I have stored in databse like trackrevisions,protection etc. Now I just want only one thing to happen. I want to convert the binary data efficiently back to text(string) which was origianlly stored in the database.
Here are some ways I am trying to get text back from binary but all of them return symbols(format not supported) rather than text.

```
string str1 = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
string x = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes).ToLower();
```

Any suggestions

Comment: Why are you trying to convert it to a string?

Comment: You saved a MS Word file. Why do you expect you can convert the binary data to text?

Comment: @ThorstenKranz : the problem is I have applied trackrevisons on the file which i stored in DB. But I was unable to convert MS Word file to pdf, so I am trying to display it in read only mode.But now when I retrieve it I can edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Making a Word document read only is something you do before saving it (Word.Document.Protect())
2. If you are using .docx - it is xml, therefore already text (utf8)

Comment: yes kevin, I did it already but that was while uploading it in DB. Now I want to rule out the changes and put new readonly protection , previously i had put Only revisions chanages

Answer (score 1):

MS Word files are not  ["plain text"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_text). You cannot read them by merely using a text decoder.